# Rust generic type that can either own or borrow its content

Tags: rust

Is it possible to represent a generic struct in Rust that can either own or borrow its content? The rough idea is:

```
struct Foo<T> {
    value: T,
}

fn make_foo<'a, T: From<&'a str>>(s: &'a str) -> Foo<T> {
    Foo<T>(s.into())
}
```

However, I don't know how to constrain `T` so that it can represent either an owned value like a `String`, or a borrowed value like a `&'a str`.

Do I have to create two separate `FooOwned<T>` and `FooBorrowed<'a, T>`?

Comment: That's the idea behind the type [`Cow<'a, T>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html).

Comment: I'm not 100% sure `Cow` is actually the answer here -- both `String` and `&'a str` implement `From<&'a str>`, so the snippet you give works fine either as `make_foo::<String>` or as `make_foo::<&str>`. What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`std::borrow::Cow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html)

```
pub enum Cow<'a, B> 
where
    B: 'a + ToOwned + ?Sized, 
 {
    Borrowed(&'a B),
    Owned(<B as ToOwned>::Owned),
}
```

When you borrow the type, it either returns a reference it stores, or reference to the value it stores, but if you want to borrow from it mutably, it converts to `Owned` variant, allowing you to take mutable reference to whatever it stores.

Which is why it's named `Cow` - Copy on Write. It implicitly copies, often in form of `clone`, whenever you access it in a way that allows writing.

It's not so implicit in a sense that you have to explicitly convert it to `Owned`, using [`to_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html#method.to_mut), which has this example given to you:

```
use std::borrow::Cow;

let mut cow = Cow::Borrowed("foo");
cow.to_mut().make_ascii_uppercase();

assert_eq!(
  cow,
  Cow::Owned(String::from("FOO")) as Cow<str>
);
```

It's implementation is not as simple, but it's [source code](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/borrow.rs.html#171-183) is fairly easy to follow, `to_mut`, which is what you might be interested in, is implemented in [`line 228`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/borrow.rs.html#228).